# Define an index which increases every time that finds the same value in a certain column in r data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table like the following:

```
example <- data.table(time = 1:30,
                  A = c(rep("a", 5), rep("b", 5), rep("a", 5), 
                        rep("b", 2), rep("a", 8), rep("b", 3), rep("a", 2)))
```

I need a way to assign an increasing index based on column A, so that the output would look like this:

```
time A B
  1  a 1
  2  a 1
  3  a 1
  4  a 1
  5  a 1
  6  b 1
  7  b 1
  8  b 1
  9  b 1
 10  b 1
 11  a 2
 12  a 2
 13  a 2
 14  a 2
 15  a 2
 16  b 2
 17  b 2
 18  a 3
 19  a 3
 20  a 3
 21  a 3
 22  a 3
 23  a 3
 24  a 3
 25  a 3
 26  b 3
 27  b 3
 28  b 3
 29  a 4
 30  a 4
```

I can't find any easy way to do this. I'd be happy to have a solution in data.table, but anything that applies is also welcomed!

Comment: Can you clarify? It looks like you want to increment every time you come across a new instance of `"a"`, but not `"b"`. Is that correct?

Comment: In a way, yes, one can see the problem from that perspective, because afterwards I can filter out for the group that is interesting. But the general idea behind is that one increments the index according to the group: So I start with 1 for all the groups (here, "a" and "b", but it could be more), and I increment every time that the sequence of that group is interrupted.

Comment: As long as the sequence always starts with the same entry ("a" in your example) and that entry is not part of the sequence later, you can use my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```r
example[, B:= cumsum(c(A[1] == 'a', diff(A == 'a') == 1))]
```

Result:

```r
example
    time A B
 1:    1 a 1
 2:    2 a 1
 3:    3 a 1
 4:    4 a 1
 5:    5 a 1
 6:    6 b 1
 7:    7 b 1
 8:    8 b 1
 9:    9 b 1
10:   10 b 1
11:   11 a 2
12:   12 a 2
13:   13 a 2
14:   14 a 2
15:   15 a 2
16:   16 b 2
17:   17 b 2
18:   18 a 3
19:   19 a 3
20:   20 a 3
21:   21 a 3
22:   22 a 3
23:   23 a 3
24:   24 a 3
25:   25 a 3
26:   26 b 3
27:   27 b 3
28:   28 b 3
29:   29 a 4
30:   30 a 4
    time A B
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming two levels we can consider `rleid` modulo 2. It iterates between -1 and 1, what we want is 1.

```
> library(data.table)
> example[, B := cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(rleid(A) %% 2) == 1L)) + 1L]
> example
    time A B
 1:    1 a 1
 2:    2 a 1
 3:    3 a 1
 4:    4 a 1
 5:    5 a 1
 6:    6 b 1
 7:    7 b 1
 8:    8 b 1
 9:    9 b 1
10:   10 b 1
11:   11 a 2
12:   12 a 2
13:   13 a 2
14:   14 a 2
15:   15 a 2
16:   16 b 2
17:   17 b 2
18:   18 a 3
19:   19 a 3
20:   20 a 3
21:   21 a 3
22:   22 a 3
23:   23 a 3
24:   24 a 3
25:   25 a 3
26:   26 b 3
27:   27 b 3
28:   28 b 3
29:   29 a 4
30:   30 a 4
    time A B
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(example)
structure(list(time = 1:30, A = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a")), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x561952fd11c0>)
```

Answer (score 3):

Other (slightly similar) methods:

If you have only two factors in `A`, then you can ceiling on the rleid, similar to @jay.sf's approach (though no modulus):

```r
example[, B1 := ceiling(rleid(A)/2) ]
```

... though I think that can be generalized a little to how many unique `A` exist.

```r
example[, B2 := ceiling(rleid(A) / uniqueN(A))]
```

Both of those assume that they always occur *in sequence*; if not (e.g., `a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c,b,b,b,a,a,a,c,c,c`), then we may need this last one.

Another `cumsum`-related method is to use `rleid` for initial grouping.

```r
example[, B2 := c(A[1] == "a", rep(0, .N-1)), by = rleid(A)][, B2 := cumsum(B2)]
```